# is there a sql query for finding if a table consists some rows that have specific value in them where the value is not the same to all rows search

Tags: mysql, sql

For example I have a table x that has columns (col1,col2,col3)
and it has the values

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 7 |
| 5 | 8 | 7 |

and I want to get true if the table contains for all col1=1 and that both 3 and 7 are good values for col3 meaning to search for every row with col1=1 and col3=3 or 7. I tried doing so with contains but I failed. also is it possible to want that for the value 2 in col1 i will have 3 in col3 and for the value 1 in col1 i will have 7 in col3? thank a lot
if someone can help me I will be very thankful. thank you all

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you are after: You want to select one value, true or false. In your example you will return true, because all rows with col1 = 1 match col3 in (3,7). If there were a row with col1 = 1 and col3 not in (3,7), you would return false. Is this correct?

Comment: yes you got it right

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with simple `where` clause as below:

DB-Fiddle:

```
 select * from x where col1=1 and col3 in (3,7)
```

Output:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 7 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aa845a9fc59fe01c495903096e2f414c)*

To calculate an extra column having true or false:

```
 select col1,col2,col3,
 (case when col1=1 and col3 in (3,7) then 'true' else 'false' end)validate from x
```

Output:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | validate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | true |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | false |
| 1 | 2 | 7 | true |
| 5 | 8 | 7 | false |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb7c3b55a65662d16bc620a539d2ee10)*

As mentioned in comment:

```
 select col1,col2,col3,
 (case when (col1=2 and col3 = 3) or (col1=1 and col3 = 7) then 'true' else 'false' end)validate from x
```

Output:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | validate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | false |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | false |
| 1 | 2 | 7 | true |
| 5 | 8 | 7 | false |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2603a7154f081543de35e70bd3c3410c)*

Comment: also is it possible to want that for the value 2 in col1 i will have 3 in col3 and for the value 1 in col1 i will have 7 in col3? thank a lot

Comment: Sure. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this request:

Select * from x
where (Col1 = 1 and Col3 =3 )
or (Col1 = 1 and Col3 =7)

Comment: now i get a true weather i have 1 row that meet to the request while in my case i need the table to meet all of the terms to return true, maybe i should put and instead of of? but my guess is that it will return false no matter what because the values cant be both in the same row

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You want to select one value, true or false. In your example you will return true, because all rows with `col1 = 1` match the condition `col3 in (3,7)`. If there were a row with `col1 = 1 and col3 not in (3,7)` you would return false.

So let's see whether there are mismatches in the table. If so, the result shall be false otherwise true.

This simple query does this:

```
select
  not max(col1 = 1 and col3 not in (3,7)) as is_okay
from mytable;
```

We are selecting the maximum for a boolean expression. In MySQL true = 1, false = 0. So if we find a mismatch then the result is 1 (true), else 0 (false). And with `NOT` we make it vice versa, i.e. get true when there is no mismatch.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=229038965ccf8429ec783139063dbdfb